# QHBoxLayout inside QFormLayout not left aligned

Tags: qt

I have following chunk of simple code:

```
UeDisplaySettingsWidget::UeDisplaySettingsWidget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    this->setLayout(new QFormLayout());
    this->ueSetDisplayDimmerSelectorLayout(new QHBoxLayout());

    this->ueSetDisplayDimmerSelectorLabel(new QLabel(tr("Display fade level:"),
                                                     this));

    this->ueInitDisplayDimmerLevelSelector();
    this->ueInitDisplayDimmerTimeoutSelector();

    connect(this->ueDisplayDimmerSelector(),
            &QSlider::valueChanged,
            this,
            &UeDisplaySettingsWidget::ueSlotDisplayDimerSelectorValueChanged);

    this->ueDisplayDimmerSelectorLayout()->addWidget(this->ueDisplayDimmerSelectorLabel());
    this->ueDisplayDimmerSelectorLayout()->addWidget(this->ueDisplayDimmerSelector());
    this->ueDisplayDimmerSelectorLayout()->addWidget(this->ueDisplayDimmerCurrentLevelIndicator());

    dynamic_cast<QFormLayout*>(this->layout())->addItem(this->ueDisplayDimmerSelectorLayout());
    dynamic_cast<QFormLayout*>(this->layout())->addRow(tr("Display fade timeout:"),
                                                       this->ueDisplayDimmerTimeoutSelector());
}   // constructor
```

which produces following output:
[image: QHBoxLayout problem]

Now, why [QHBoxLayout](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhboxlayout.html#details) returned by `this->ueDisplayDimmerSelectorLayout()` and containing [QLabel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#details) with text *Display fade level:*, [QSlider](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qslider.html#details) and [QLCDNumber](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlcdnumber.html#details) is not aligned with lower row of [QFormLayout](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qformlayout.html#details)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QFormLayout is basically a grid layout with two columns where you have labels in the left column and whatever in the right.

For some reason you but that fade out label this->ueDisplayDimmerSelectorLabel() in the horizontal layout and use QFormLayout::addItem(QLayoutItem*) for your first row and QFormLayout::addRow(const QString &, QWidget*)) for the second row. Thats why your DisplayDimmerSlectorLabel is together with its widget in the second column. Wtihout having it tested it should look something like this:

```
connect(this->ueDisplayDimmerSelector(),
        &QSlider::valueChanged,
        this,
        &UeDisplaySettingsWidget::ueSlotDisplayDimerSelectorValueChanged);

this->ueDisplayDimmerSelectorLayout()->addWidget(this->ueDisplayDimmerSelector());
this->ueDisplayDimmerSelectorLayout()->addWidget(this->ueDisplayDimmerCurrentLevelIndicator());

dynamic_cast<QFormLayout*>(this->layout())->addRow(tr("Display fade level:"), this->ueDisplayDimmerSelectorLayout());
dynamic_cast<QFormLayout*>(this->layout())->addRow(tr("Display fade timeout:"),
                                                   this->ueDisplayDimmerTimeoutSelector());
```